# React: passed element doesn't instantiate

Tags: reactjs

Basic ReactJS question. I have the following React components:

```
var TopLevelElement = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <Grouper top={Top} bottom={Bottom} />
        );
    }
});

var Grouper = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="top">{this.props.top}</div>
                <div className="bottom">{this.props.bottom}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

`Top` and `Bottom` are React components that just have a render() that outputs some markup.

When I do a `React.render(<TopLevelElement />, el);` it only outputs the markup in Grouper, not in `Top` or `Bottom`. I've confirmed that those elements do work fine independently.

Looks like the children aren't being instantiated at all. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var TopLevelElement = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <Grouper top={<Top />} bottom={<Bottom />} />
        );
    }
});
```